# select first 10 rows, then decide which rows to include afterwards

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 columns in table. The 1st column represents the name of different companies and the 2nd column displays the count of products.

```
COL 1         COL 2
CompA         2323
CompB         2320
CompC         1999
CompD         1598
CompE         1400...so on
```

What i want to do is to display first 10 rows showing first 10 companies name and its count in desc order. 
Then I want to compare 10th company count with 11th company count. If they match, then display 11th company name and its count. If 10th company count doesn't match 11th company count, then display first 10 records only.

I have read only access so I can't update or insert new records in table.

How can this be done?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: What if the 11th through 15th companies all match the 10th company's count?

Comment: @Thomas -- In that case i need to show till 15th company name. Good catch

Answer (score 7):

If what you want to do is display the top ten counts, including ties.  This is simple to solve with an ANALYTIC function such as `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` ...

```
SQL> select * from
  2      ( select
  3          ename
  4             , sal
  5             , rank() over (order by sal desc) sal_rank
  6      from emp
  7      )
  8  where sal_rank <= 10
  9  /

ENAME             SAL   SAL_RANK
---------- ---------- ----------
QUASSNOI         6500          1
SCHNEIDER        5000          2
FEUERSTEIN       4500          3
VERREYNNE        4000          4
LIRA             3750          5
PODER            3750          5
KESTELYN         3500          7
TRICHLER         3500          7
GASPAROTTO       3000          9
ROBERTSON        2990         10
RIGBY            2990         10

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Note that if RIGBY had had the same salary as GASPAROTTO, their SAL_RANK would have been **9**, ROBERTSON's would have been **11** and the result set would have comprised ten rows.

`DENSE_RANK()` differs from `RANK()` in that it always returns the top ten whatevers, instead of skipping ties...

```
SQL> select * from
  2      ( select
  3          ename
  4             , sal
  5             , dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) sal_rank
  6      from emp
  7      )
  8  where sal_rank <= 10
  9  /

ENAME             SAL   SAL_RANK
---------- ---------- ----------
                               1
SCHNEIDER        5000          2
FEUERSTEIN       4500          3
VERREYNNE        4000          4
LIRA             3750          5
PODER            3750          5
KESTELYN         3500          6
TRICHLER         3500          6
GASPAROTTO       3000          7
ROBERTSON        2990          8
RIGBY            2990          8
SPENCER          2850          9
BOEHMER          2450         10

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM (
   SELECT col1, col2
     FROM Table
     WHERE col2 >= (SELECT col2
                      FROM (SELECT col2 FROM Table ORDER BY col2 DESC) t1
                     WHERE t1.ROWNUM = 10)
     ORDER BY col2 DESC) t2
WHERE t2.ROWNUM <= 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are saying can be done by writing a pl/sql block of code of top-n query.
some thing like this would help

```
decalre
    v_col_1    companies.col_1%TYPE;
    v_col_2    companies.col_2%TYPE;
    count number;    
    col_2_all number;
    CURSOR companies is SELECT *
        FROM (select * from companies ORDER BY col_2) 
        WHERE rownum <= 10
        ORDER BY rownum;

begin

    loop 
      fetch companies into v_cal_1,v_col_2;
      count++;
      if count =10 then
        col_2_all=v_col_2
        dbms_output.put_line('company name'||v_cal_1||'company count'||v_cal_2);
      elsif count =11 then
        if col_2_all=v_col_2 then
          dbms_output.put_line('company name'||v_cal_1||'company count'||v_cal_2);
        end if;
      end if;
    EXIT WHEN count>11;

end;
```

i am not sure about the syntax but it has to be something like this :)

Comment: Syntax errors aside, this is not a good way to solve such problems.  Never use PL/SQL to do what can be done with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Top10Co As
    (
    Select Col1 As CompanyName, Col2 As Cnt
        , Row_Number() Over ( Order By Col2 Desc ) As Num
    From MyTable
    )
Select CompanyName, Cnt
From Top10Co
Where Num <= 10
Union All
Select Col1, Col2
From MyTable
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Top10Co As T2
                Where T2.Num = 10
                    And T2.CompanyName <> MyTable.Col1
                    And T2.Cnt = MyTable.Col2
                )
```